# Android: how do I make EditText Hint clickable?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have a UI with EditText lines for user input.  The first EditText line has focus when the UI is created and I use setHint "Home" on the EditText to add a Hint to the EditText line.  The EditText is wrapped in a TextInputLayout in the layout file so that when the user types any input, the Hint disappears and a FloatingLabel equal to the Hint (in this case "Home") appears above the EditText line.  I want to make only the Hint, on the EditText line, be clickable so that it can be used to launch a Spinner dialog.  Can the Hint only be set to be clickable?

Activity file

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private EditText aEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_edit);

        aEditText = (EditText) findViewById(id.AEditText);
        aEditText.setHint("Home");
    }
}
```

activity_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".Activity">   

...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/To_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FloatingLabel"  >        

<com.v071.widget.ListenerEditText
    android:id="@+id/AEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_primary"  />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

...
```

Comment: You can't make the hint text from TextInputLayout clickable, because it's not a View. It's drawn directly on top of the actual EditText. But you can make the whole EditText clickable and ignore the clicks when it's non-empty.

Comment: @BladeCoder  That sounds good, can you show example for ignoring clicks when it's non-empty?

Comment: I think you want to show the spinner once you are done with the editing. Am I correct? In this case rather than click on the editText, can you not listen for enter or done key on soft keypad to show the spinner?

Comment: No, I want to click on the EditText.  That launches the spinner.  And then selecting one of the list items from the spinner dialog will update the EditText Hint.

Comment: `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText()) showSpinner();`

Comment: @BladeCoder  Ah, got it thanks.  And "showSpinner()" is not an Android Spinner method, it will be the method that I create to launch the Spinner?

Comment: That's your code yes. But you should probably use an AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView instead of a simple EditText.

Comment: Ok.  What advantage does AutoCompleteTextView offer versus EditText?